# Future 'int' to int a chart from database

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently trying to convert Future 'int' to int but looking around I have a hard time understanding how to resolve it. Is there a way I can convert the database data to int?

**Database Method**

```
Future<int> queryGetPlastic() async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    //return Sqflite.firstIntValue(await db.rawQuery('SELECT plastic from $table '));
    return Sqflite.firstIntValue(await db.rawQuery('SELECT cast(plastic AS INTEGER) from $table order by _id DESC limit 1'));
  }

  Future<int> queryGetPaper() async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    //return Sqflite.firstIntValue(await db.rawQuery('SELECT plastic from $table '));
    return Sqflite.firstIntValue(await db.rawQuery('SELECT cast(metal AS INTEGER) from $table order by _id DESC limit 1'));
  }

  Future<int> queryGetMetal() async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    //return Sqflite.firstIntValue(await db.rawQuery('SELECT plastic from $table '));
    return Sqflite.firstIntValue(await db.rawQuery('SELECT cast(paper AS INTEGER) from $table order by _id DESC limit 1'));
  }
```

So basically with the methods, I tried

**Chart data with its widget**

```
//since it's future int

      var data = [
        Waste('Metal', dbHelper.queryGetMetal(), Colors.red),
        Waste('Paper', dbHelper.queryGetPaper(), Colors.yellow),
        Waste('Plastic', dbHelper.queryGetPlastic(), Colors.blue),
      ];

      var series = [
        charts.Series(
          domainFn: (Waste clickData, _) => clickData.type,
          measureFn: (Waste clickData, _) => clickData.count,
          colorFn: (Waste clickData, _) => clickData.color,
          id: 'Clicks',
          data: data,
        ),
      ];

      var chart = charts.BarChart(
        series,
        animate: true,
      );

      var chartWidget = Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 200.0,
          child: chart,
        ),
      );
```

```
: Container(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(''),
                  Text(''),
                  Text('Welcome!'),
                  //Text('$genwaste'),
                  chartWidget,
........................................
```

i thought that if i used async it would convert it to int but it return to future int

```
 void _plastic() async {
      int plastic = await dbHelper.queryGetPlastic();
    }

    _metal() async {
      int plastic = await dbHelper.queryGetMetal();
      return plastic;
    }

    _paper() async {
      int plastic = await dbHelper.queryGetPaper();
      return plastic;
    }
```

Comment: I can recommend you read: https://medium.com/@jelenaaa.lecic/when-to-use-async-await-then-and-future-in-dart-5e00e64ab9b1 and https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await to get a basic understanding of asynchronous programming.

Answer (score 0):

A Future object is the result of a delayed computation to get your value you need to use the `await` keyword.

```dart
var data = [
   Waste('Metal', await dbHelper.queryGetMetal(), Colors.red),
   Waste('Paper', await dbHelper.queryGetPaper(), Colors.yellow),
   Waste('Plastic', await dbHelper.queryGetPlastic(), Colors.blue),
];
```

Comment: i am getting that i need to mark the function body with async?

Comment: Yes because when you do asynchronous operation you must have the `async` keyword too so the `await` can work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of .then to convert Future`<int`> to int

```
void _plastic() async {
       int plastic;
       await dbHelper.queryGetPlastic().then((value) {
           plastic = value
          });
    }
```

same for other

Refer to flutter doc: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html

Comment: i did this but when i tried to return it, it would give me Future ''int" can't be assigned to parameter type int. the same error as before

Comment: I don't think so... check the link of flutter doc: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html 
for future handling... this is the way to do it